# Как выполнить JavaScript через определенное время?

Tags: javascript

Нужно через 5 секунд после загрузки страницы выполнить javascript файл, который находиться на удаленном сервере, и доступен по ссылке:

> https://site.ru/folder/script.js

Как лучше всего это реализовать?

Я думал сделать так:

```js
var sec = 5;

function sleep() {
 if (sec > 0)sec--;
 if (sec == 0) {
    //если прошло 5 сек, как выполнить JS ?
    sec  = -1;
 }
}

setInterval(sleep, 1000);
```

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){/* ваш код через 5 сек */}, 5000);`. всё.

Comment: @Lexx918 дело в том что не кодом вставляю, а нужно именно ссылкой на JS файл, так как он очень большой

Answer (score 3):

Я так понял речь про это?

```
setTimeout(function() {
    let script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("src","https://site.ru/folder/script.js");
    document.body.appendChild(script)
}, 5000);
```

этот код через 5сек после выполнения создаст на странице тег `script`, чем заставит браузер скачать и выполнить его, но надо понимать что он выполнится через 5 сек + время загрузки

Answer (score 1):

```
function funcToExec() {
  // function body
}

setTimeout(() => {funcToExec()}, 5000);
```

Но я не уверен, что функция с другого ресурса выполнется.

Comment: У вас тут ошибочка.

Comment: а как выполнить именно JS файл?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko поясните.

Comment: Ваша функция `funcToExec` не будет вызывана через 5 секунд, а будет вызвана сразу.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko хочешь сделать этот мир лучше, помогай. Просто критиковать каждый может. Я-то разберусь в чем была ошибка, а вот кто-то не сможет, вероятно. Пример исправил.

Comment: А я разве не помогаю? Нашел ошбку, вам на нее указал, ваш ответ стал лучше.